# Node.js Express.js Send Jquery Ajax Post throws Constant Error - I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to make a very simple return coming from Node.js to Ajax. I'm using Express.js to make this possible.

I have code from the previous route that I did in order to write and manage JSON files and it works just fine.

The problem comes from the second route that always throws an error when I'm trying to make it return something with the JQuery ajax success method. It is the most simple form of send that I found but still doesn't work.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test 2</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Cod: <input type="text" name="cod" id="cod">
    Text: <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <button id="boton">PRUEBA</button>
    <button id="getText">GET TEXT</button>
    
    <script>
        $('#boton').click(function() {
            let cod=$('#cod').val();
            let text=$('#text').val();
            console.log(cod);
            console.log(text);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    cod: cod,
                    text: text,
                },
                url: 'http://localhost:1337/prueba'
            });
        });
        $('#getText').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {

                },
                success: (result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: (result) => {
                    console.log('ERROR');
                },
                url: 'http://localhost:1337/getText'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/prueba', function(req, res) {
    // ... First Route. The code here works just fine so I don't add it here.
});

app.post('/getText', function(req, res) {
    let text = "Hola mundo";
    console.log(text);

    res.send(text);
});

app.listen(1337, () => console.log('Started server at http://localhost:1337!'));
```

When you click the 'GET TEXT' Button it enters inside the '/getText' route in app.js and console.logs the text on the node.js terminal so that's not the issue.

The issue seems to come from the res.send() function.

In the browser console it logs 'ERROR' as it appears in the ajax error method associated to the 'GET TEXT' Button. I can't find a way to make it return success.

Could anyone help me? I'm so stuck with this project for work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue... do you serve index.html from the same location?

It works serving index.html from node

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/prueba', function(req, res) {
    // ... First Route. The code here works just fine so I don't add it here.
});

app.post('/getText', function(req, res) {
    let text = "Hola mundo";
    console.log(text);

    res.send(text);
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {   
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: '.'})
   })

app.listen(1337, () => console.log('Started server at http://localhost:1337!'));
```

There are several options for node/express, e.g. [express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: Yes the index.html is in the same location.

Comment: complete sample added. Works on my machine ;-)

Comment: I did 'npm install cors' and it worked. Thank you!!! <33333. I added a few lines of code from the express middleware link that you shared and it worked.